# Set macro for Latex

Tags: arrays

I would like to define a macro for writing sets easily. E.g.:

```tex
\set{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
```

which then becomes something like

```latex
\{ 1,\ 2,\ 3,\ 4,\ 5\, \}  % this
\begin{Bmatrix}\, 1,\, 2,\, 3 ,\, 4,\, 5\, \end{Bmatrix}   % or this
```

Additionally I would need:

- possibility to change the braces: e.g. \set[p]{ 1, 2, 3 }
- possibility to change the delimiter: e.g. replace comma with space
- automatic line breaks as part of paragraph justification allowed after each comma

Currently I adapted something I found here:
[Change how to enter a matrix in Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130191/change-how-to-enter-a-matrix-in-latex),
which resulted in this code (for the macro `\tset`):

```latex
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\tset}{ O{B} m }
 {
  \strategy_tset:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_strategy_rows_seq
\seq_new:N \l_strategy_a_row_seq
\tl_new:N \l_strategy_matrix_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \strategy_tset:nn #1 #2
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l_strategy_matrix_tl
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_strategy_rows_seq { ; } { #2 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_strategy_rows_seq
   {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_strategy_a_row_seq { , } { ##1 }
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_strategy_matrix_tl { \seq_use:Nn \l_strategy_a_row_seq { , } }
   }
  \begin{#1matrix}
  \, \tl_use:N \l_strategy_matrix_tl \,
  \end{#1matrix}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

which I think is far from good. In paritcular, the line breaking does not work.

Comment: by line breaking do you mean allowing `\\ ` in the input or, for inline math allow automatic line breaking as part of paragraph justification (which would mean you would not want to base this on `bmatrix` which makes an unbreakable box)

Comment: Automatic line breaking as part of paragraph justification. I edited my question. That answers why adding `\allowbreak` did not worked.

Comment: My package `semantex` was more or less built to provide interfaces like this. But it takes some work setting it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a key-value based code for deciding the separator and the delimiters. A line break is possible only after the second item and before the last-but-one item.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\tset}{O{}m}
 {
  \strategy_tset_main:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__strategy_tset_items_seq
\str_new:N \l__strategy_tset_delim_str
\tl_new:N \l__strategy_tset_sep_tl
\tl_new:N \l__strategy_tset_last_tl

\keys_define:nn { strategy/tset }
 {
  B .code:n = \str_set:Nn \l__strategy_tset_delim_str { B },
  p .code:n = \str_set:Nn \l__strategy_tset_delim_str { p },
  b .code:n = \str_set:Nn \l__strategy_tset_delim_str { b },
  comma .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l__strategy_tset_sep_tl { , },
  space .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l__strategy_tset_sep_tl { \ },
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \strategy_tset_main:nn
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { strategy/tset } { B, comma, #1 }
  % left delimiter
  \str_case:Vn \l__strategy_tset_delim_str
   {
    {B}{\{}
    {p}{(}
    {b}{[}
   }
  % items with separators
  \tl_if_blank:nF { #2 }
   {
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__strategy_tset_items_seq { #2 }
    \seq_pop_right:NN \l__strategy_tset_items_seq \l__strategy_tset_last_tl
    \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l__strategy_tset_items_seq
     {
      ##2 % the item
      \tl_use:N \l__strategy_tset_sep_tl % the separator
       % add \linebreak[0] only after the second and before the last but one item
      \int_compare:nT { 1 < ##1 < \seq_count:N \l__strategy_tset_items_seq }
       {
        \linebreak[0]
       }
     }
    \tl_use:N \l__strategy_tset_last_tl % the last item
   }
   % right delimiter
  \str_case:Vn \l__strategy_tset_delim_str
   {
    {B}{\}}
    {p}{)}
    {b}{]}
   }
  \group_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\tset{1,2,3,4}$

$\tset[space,b]{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p}$

Some words words ww $\tset[space,b]{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p}$

Some words words words $\tset[space,b]{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p}$

Some words ww $\tset[p]{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p}$

Some words words words words words www $\tset[comma,p]{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p}$

$\tset{}$

$
\tset[p]{
  1,
  \tset[b]{
    2,
    3,
    \tset[{B,space}]{
      a,
      b,
      c
    },
    4
  },
  5
}
$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd not increase the space after commas; if you really want, use something like

```
  comma .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l__strategy_tset_sep_tl { ,\; },
```

As you see, nesting is possible, but if more options are needed in a nested `\tset`, you need to enclose them in braces as shown in the last example.

A check is made whether the argument is blank, in this case just the delimiters are printed.

Comment: It seems while copy-pasting to stackexchange, something broke. When I try to compile this, I get a lot of errors. Starting with `Undefined control sequence $\tset{1,2,3,4}$.`

Comment: @tommsch Probably you have an outdated TeX distribution. Add `\usepackage{xparse}` and retry.

Comment: I forgot to mention, These errors come with `\usepackage{xparse}` added.

Comment: @tommsch Please, add the *precise* error message you find in the log file.

Comment: Here it is: justpaste.it/68ts1

Comment: @tommsch Why don't you regularly update your MiKTeX distribution? You have a three-year-old LaTeX.

Comment: Because if I want to publish anything and the journal has an old tex version, its likely that I use something that they cannot compile. Also, 3 years is not that old.

Comment: @tommsch Sorry, but three years *is* old.

Comment: I updated my miktex. Now it works, but I cant compile anything omplicated anymore, because something broke -- Theres another reason for not updating: Never change a running system :) . Nevertheless, thanks for the effort. The macro works great.

Comment: Sorry, Would it be possible to fix this bug: `\tset{}` does not work. If not, nevermind.

Comment: @tommsch “Does not work” is too generic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132315/discussion-between-tommsch-and-egreg).

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This is just using `clist` to map over the comma list, and then undoing the final "comma" spacing with `\unskip`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\set[2][\{]{
#1
\clist_map_inline:nn{#2}{##1\nolinebreak[2]\;}
\unskip\unpenalty
\ifx\{#1\}\else
\ifx(#1)\else
?\fi\fi}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

$\set{1,2,3}$  $\set[(]{1,2,3}$ 

some test text some test text some test text 
$\set{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Some questions: 1) I do not understand how the parentheses are done (especially the opening brace) , e.g. `[` is not possible. 2) Which command enables line breaking here?

Comment: you can use `\lbrack` for `[` inside the [] argument (that is a standard latex, and plain tex alias for [ linebreaking is enabled by `\nolinebreak[2]` which is a mild discouragement to break, so allows breaking @tommsch

Comment: If I use anything but `(` and `{`, then the closing bracket defaults to a `?`.

Comment: @tommsch oh yes sorry I should have comented in the question you would need to add to that `\ifx` set so add a line  `\ifx\lbrack#1\rbrack\else`  and an extra `\fi` at the end

Comment: My actual question was, how to change the opening brace, so I can use for example `p` for parentheses.

Comment: @tommsch you could use `p` I thought `(`  was easier to read to  use `p` instead of `(` just change `\ifx(#1)\else` to `\ifx p#1)\else`  and add a similar test but with `\ifx p #1(\else` at the start replacing the `#1` that I used. I show parenthesis exampe(1 2 3) in the answer above